# riak os x installation

Tags: macos, installation, riak

I am trying to get the 4 node riak setup working on my os x lion machine.

I installed riak using

```
$ brew install riak
```

I am using the online documentation available - http://wiki.basho.com/Building-a-Development-Environment.html

I am stuck on this step - "Use rebar to start up four nodes. "

After installing riak, do I have to install rebar as well? After installing riak I directly tried the

```
$ make devrel
```

command and it gave the following error

```
make: *** No rule to make target `devrel'.  Stop.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using brew to install Riak will not give you the ability to run 4 nodes. If you're going to build a development setup you should build from source.

I wrote a [tutorial](http://buffered.io/posts/webmachine-erlydtl-and-riak-part-1/) (as part of a [blog series](http://buffered.io/series/web-development-with-erlang/)) which shows how you can get a dev cluster running after installing Erlang. I haven't updated it to reflect changes in v1.1.4 yet, but for the most part this should help you get started.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

To hopefully help others, like me today, I'm posting this. Make sure that Erlang is correctly installed by running

```
$ erl
#if ok, quit with 'q()'
1> q()
```

I thought it it was installed, but it wasn't and I got that completely uninformative errormsg. It should've said "dude, you need to install erlang first".